# Split list into lists by particular value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
['S1', 'S2', 'S6', 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S1', 'S2', 'S5', 'S1',
 'S2', 'S4', 'S5', 'S1', 'S2', 'S4', 'S5', 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S6']
```

and I want to split by next S1:

```
[['S1', 'S2', 'S6']['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5'],['S1', 'S2', 'S4', 'S5]...]
```

My code is:

```
size = len(steps)
idx_list = [idx + 1 for idx, val in
            enumerate(steps) if val == 'S1'] 


res = [steps[i: j] for i, j in
        zip([0] + idx_list, idx_list + 
        ([size] if idx_list[-1] != size else []))] 

print("The list after splitting by a value : " + str(res))
```

It splits the list as:

```
[['S1'], ['S2', 'S6', 'S1'], ['S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S1'], 
 ['S2', 'S5', 'S1'], ['S2', 'S4', 'S5', 'S1'], ['S2', 'S4', 'S5', 'S1']..
```

Can you please help to rectify it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). Change the following line:

```
idx_list = [idx + 1 for idx, val in
            enumerate(steps) if val == 'S1']
```

to

```
idx_list = [idx for idx, val in
            enumerate(steps) if val == 'S1' and idx > 0]
```

The result should then be:

```
[['S1', 'S2', 'S6'], ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5'], 
 ['S1', 'S2', 'S5'], ['S1', 'S2', 'S4', 'S5'], 
 ['S1', 'S2', 'S4', 'S5'], ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S6']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = ['S1', 'S2', 'S6', 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S1', 'S2', 'S5', 'S1', 'S2', 'S4', 'S5', 'S1', 'S2', 'S4', 'S5', 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S6']

splitby = 'S1'
res = [[splitby] + list(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x != splitby) if k]

# [['S1', 'S2', 'S6'], ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5'], ['S1', 'S2', 'S5'], ['S1', 'S2', 'S4', 'S5'], ['S1', 'S2', 'S4', 'S5'], ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S6']]
```